# How can I password protect & let cgi-bin to work?

Tags: ubuntu, apache-2.2, scriptalias

This is taken from sites-available directory. It's a virtual host setting for apache.

Accessing myiphere/cgi-bin/ throws 403.

The directory setting for /var/www2/ `drwxrwxrwx 8 www-data www-data`

```
NameVirtualHost  myiphere
<VirtualHost  myiphere>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www2/
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www2/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
            AllowOverride None
            Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined
    ServerSignature On

Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
<Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
</Directory>
```

Comment: What if you access myiphere/cgi-bin/some-existing-script instead? The directory itself should give 403, because `Options Indexes` is not enabled (which is the proper setting for such directory), but actual scripts should work.

Comment: You really really don't want to have full write-access to your web content directory. At the very least remove write access for `other`.

Answer (score 1):

`NameVirtualHost  myiphere`

NEVER use hostnames for vhosts; use the following (default) instead: `NameVirtualHost  *:80`

`<VirtualHost  myiphere>`

Same goes here.

```
<Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
</Directory>
```

This does not belong inside a vhost; you set this ONCE, in the main server config.

```
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
<Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
```

Don't alter CGI options inside a scriptalias; this is all done *for* you.

Start with the following corrected setup, and remember that without the ServerName, NOTHING works.

```
<Directory />
  Options FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride None
</Directory>

NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>

  ServerName test.local

  ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
  DocumentRoot /var/www2/

  <Directory /var/www2/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
  </Directory>

  ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
  <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
  </Directory>

  ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
  LogLevel warn
  CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined
  ServerSignature On

</VirtualHost>
```